# Check if string start with an Array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of strings :
`listOfTypes = ['blogPost', 'work']`

And I have a routeName
`routeName = blogPost-slug` or `routeName = blogPost`;

When `routeName` contains = `blogPost` I want to return string "page".
If `routeName` start with `string-` (example: `blogPost-`), I want to return the type (from `listOfTypes`)

I made a forEach function that works. Only, I get several results (it's normal) when I only want one (if it is present in the array, then I return either the type or `page`)

```js
listOfTypes = ['blogPost', 'work'];

// routeName is retrieved dynamically. This is for example, "blogPost" or "blogPost-slug" or "work-slug"

listOfTypes.forEach(type => {
      // Check if route name starts with type + "-" because it's separator with subroute 
      // (/blogPost is a page, /blogPost-slug is a blogPost so check for blogPost-)

      if(routeName.startsWith(type + '-')) {
        return console.log(type);
      } else {
        return console.log('page');
      }
    });

// result: 'blogPost' and 'page'
// expected result: 'blogPost'
```

How can I do this and only get either the type or "page" if it doesn't match?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```js
const listOfTypes = ['blogPost', 'work'];

const getType = route => 
  listOfTypes.find(type => route.startsWith(`${type}-`)) ?? 'page';

console.log( getType('blogPost') );
console.log( getType('blogPost-slug') );
console.log( getType('work-slug') );
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It's exactly what I needed.